# Xamarin - Custom Renderer no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I've been getting this error in Xamarin when I tried to make a custom switch with a textOn and textOff function. I have looked up this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26694/problem-creating-custom-renderer. And still can't figure it out yet. This is also my first time creating a custom control for Xamarin, so I may have made some beginner mistakes

Here is my code for my custom control:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]

namespace SalesKicker
{
public class CustomSwitch : Android.Widget.Switch
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextOnProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomSwitch, string>(p => p.TextOn, AppResources.CustomSwitch_DefaultTextOn);
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextOffProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomSwitch, string>(p => p.TextOff, AppResources.CustomSwitch_DefaultTextOff);

    public string TxtOn
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextOnProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextOnProperty, value); }
    }

    public string TxtOff
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextOffProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextOffProperty, value); }
    }
}

public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
//the error is being thrown here: Error CS0115: 'CustomSwitchRenderer.OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomSwitch>)': no suitable method found to override (CS0115) (SalesKicker.Droid)
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SalesKicker.CustomSwitch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var customSwitch = this.Element;

        var control = new Switch(Forms.Context)
            {
                TextOn = customSwitch.TxtOn,
                TextOff = customSwitch.TxtOff
            };

        this.SetNativeControl(control);
    }
}
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I`m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the parameter is part of the [function signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx). If you override functions, they have to have the same signature. Use `ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch>`.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
```

Comment: There are two more issues in his code,   i) He is inheriting Android.Widget.Switch in his Custom Control definition  in Forms project. Whereas he should have inherited Switch Control in Xamarin.Forms    ii) Also he is exporting the renderer in Forms project. Whereas that should have been in Android project. Check my answer

Comment: Yes you are right :) I focused just on the compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing to this

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace SalesKicker
{
public class CustomSwitch : Switch
{
public static readonly BindableProperty TextOnProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomSwitch, string>(p => p.TextOn, AppResources.CustomSwitch_DefaultTextOn);
public static readonly BindableProperty TextOffProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomSwitch, string>(p => p.TextOff, AppResources.CustomSwitch_DefaultTextOff);

public string TxtOn
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextOnProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextOnProperty, value); }
}

public string TxtOff
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextOffProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextOffProperty, value); }
}
}
}
```

This class in Xamarin.Forms project

Then,

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]
namespace SalesKicker
{
public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
//the error is being thrown here: Error CS0115: 'CustomSwitchRenderer.OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomSwitch>)': no suitable method found to override (CS0115) (SalesKicker.Droid)
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
            return;

    var customSwitch = this.Element;

    var control = new Switch(Forms.Context)
        {
            TextOn = customSwitch.TextOn,
            TextOff = customSwitch.TextOff
        };

    this.SetNativeControl(control);
}
}
}
```

This in Android Project. Tell me if you have any further issues. This should work for you.

Comment: So what you're saying is, is that the renderer should be placed inside a class in SalesKicker.Droid?

Comment: I think he can let Xamarin Forms create the control, and just modify it by setting `Control.TextOn` and `Control.TextOff`. just my 2 ct :)

Comment: So, I have to put the control in SalesKicker and the renderer inside SalesKicker.Droid?

Comment: OMG who downvotes this?! Yes, renderers always have to be located in the native project, because a renderer creates the native UI element.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe Haha.. Maybe someone who doesn't like whole code and like only snippets...